# onBackPressed not working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, back-button

i trying to make a back button working on fragment.
im using a onBackPressed.. but every compile and click back button,
the screen always go to home screen, not to go to previous fragment
whats wrong with my code?
thanks before

this my code

> ```
> public class FragmentScheduleRoom extends Fragment{
>     ListView list;
>     // Array of strings storing country names
>     String[] room = new String[] {
>             "304",
>             "305",
>             "306",
>             "307",
>             "308",
>     };
>
>     @Override
>     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
>                              Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         Log.d("ZZZ", "ada di oncreateView Schedule room");
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_schedule_room, container,
> ```
>
> false);
>               final List> aList = new ArrayList>();
>
> ```
>         for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
>             HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
>             hm.put("room", room[i]);
>             aList.add(hm);
>             // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
>             list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
>             ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), aList, R.layout.list_schedule_room, new String[]{"room"}, new
> ```
>
> int[]{R.id.room});
>
> ```
>             list.setAdapter(adapter);
>             list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
>                 @Override
>                 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
>                                         int position, long id) {
>                     String room = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.room)).getText().toString();
> //                    Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(),FragmentScheduleDetail.class);
> //                    in.putExtra("txt",day);
>                     String selectday = getArguments().getString("selectday");
>                     Fragment fragment = new FragmentScheduleDetail();
>                     Bundle data = new Bundle();
>                     data.putString("selectroom", room);
>                     data.putString("selectday", selectday);
>                     fragment.setArguments(data);
>                     FragmentManager frgManager = getFragmentManager();
>                     Log.d("tag", "ROOM SELECT: " + data.getString("selectroom"));
>                     frgManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
>                             .commit();
>                     //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You Clicked at " + aList.get(+position).get("day"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>                 }
>             });
>         }
>         return rootView;
>     }
>     public void onBackPressed() {
>         //super.onBackPressed();
>         //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "click",2000).show();
>         Fragment fragment = new FragmentScheduleDay();
>         FragmentManager frgManager = getFragmentManager();
>         frgManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
>                 .commit();
>     }
>
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the getFragmentManager().popBackStack() methods

Answer (score 0):

no need to do that bro, just do this

```
 public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

then in your previous fragment `FragmentScheduleDay` that brings you to `FragmentScheduleRoom` do this when calling  the next fragment (which is `FragmentScheduleRoom`) `transaction.addToBackStack(null);`

EDIT 1: mostly fragment replace function detaches() and attaches() fragment.. so to use your style.. use detach(old fragment); then attach(new fragment); then commit() it will work..this aint correct code formats..

try and let me know if it solves ur problem

Comment: why i cannot using super.onBackPressed();?
im using android 4.4 
is onBackPressed not working in android 4.4?
i read this http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-change-the-back-button-behaviour/

Comment: that documentation teaches you how to redefine the behavior of the backpressed().. the super.onBackPressed()..in other words enables it to work as it work.. if you want to pop up a dialog to comfirm a users action then you go with that post.. check my edit for some tips@DerrySusilo

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        // do your task here
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Hope this will work for you. It's work for me.

Comment: is the onKeyDown auto called if we press the back button?
what we need a listener?